# linq generate more SQL queries, Is performance issue arise?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

tables

```
public class JobRecruitmentTeam
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }

    ForeignKey("Job")]
    public Int32 JobID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Int32? UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("JobTeamCategory")]
    public Int32 JobTeamCategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual JobTeamCategory JobTeamCategory { get; set; }        
}

public partial class User : BaseModel
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public String Phone { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserRole")]
    public Int32 UserRoleID { get; set; }

    public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
}
```

I write  a linq like below

```
(from user in Users
join team in JobRecruitmentTeams on user.ID equals team.UserID 
where team.JobID == 54
group team by user into grp
select new {
  Name = grp.Key.FirstName + " "+ grp.Key.LastName,
  UserID = grp.Key.ID,
  Email = grp.Key.EmailAddress,
  MobilePhone = grp.Key.Phone,
  Roles = grp.Select(x=>x.JobTeamCategory.Name).ToList(),
  RoleIds = grp.Select(x=>x.JobTeamCategoryID).ToList()  
  }).Take(10)
```

when I execute this in linqPad, I see it produce 5 different queries in SQL.

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 54
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = ' '
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (10) [t3].[value] AS [Name], [t3].[ID] AS [UserID], [t3].[EmailAddress] AS [Email], [t3].[Phone] AS [MobilePhone]
FROM (
    SELECT ([t2].[FirstName] + @p1) + [t2].[LastName] AS [value], [t2].[ID], [t2].[EmailAddress], [t2].[Phone]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[LastName], [t0].[EmailAddress], [t0].[Phone]
        FROM [User] AS [t0]
        INNER JOIN [JobRecruitmentTeam] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[ID]) = [t1].[UserID]
        WHERE [t1].[JobID] = @p0
        GROUP BY [t0].[ID], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[LastName], [t0].[EmailAddress], [t0].[Password], [t0].[ZipCode], [t0].[Latitude], [t0].[Longitude], [t0].[Address], [t0].[CityName], [t0].[CityID], [t0].[CountryID], [t0].[StateID], [t0].[RatingScaleCategoryID], [t0].[GenderID], [t0].[Phone], [t0].[Photo], [t0].[PhotoFileName], [t0].[PhotoFileSize], [t0].[UserRoleID], [t0].[IsActive], [t0].[CreatedByUserID], [t0].[CreatedByCompanyID], [t0].[LastLoginDate], [t0].[CreateDate], [t0].[LastUpdateDate], [t0].[IsArchived], [t0].[PhoneOffice]
        ) AS [t2]
    ) AS [t3]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 54
DECLARE @x1 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t2].[Name]
FROM [User] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [JobRecruitmentTeam] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[ID]) = [t1].[UserID]
INNER JOIN [JobTeamCategory] AS [t2] ON [t2].[ID] = [t1].[JobTeamCategoryID]
WHERE (@x1 = [t0].[ID]) AND ([t1].[JobID] = @p0)
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 54
DECLARE @x1 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t1].[JobTeamCategoryID]
FROM [User] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [JobRecruitmentTeam] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[ID]) = [t1].[UserID]
WHERE (@x1 = [t0].[ID]) AND ([t1].[JobID] = @p0)
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 54
DECLARE @x1 Int = 47
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t2].[Name]
FROM [User] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [JobRecruitmentTeam] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[ID]) = [t1].[UserID]
INNER JOIN [JobTeamCategory] AS [t2] ON [t2].[ID] = [t1].[JobTeamCategoryID]
WHERE (@x1 = [t0].[ID]) AND ([t1].[JobID] = @p0)
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 54
DECLARE @x1 Int = 47
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t1].[JobTeamCategoryID]
FROM [User] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [JobRecruitmentTeam] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[ID]) = [t1].[UserID]
WHERE (@x1 = [t0].[ID]) AND ([t1].[JobID] = @p0)
```

Is there any performance issue arise by my linq query.
Is there any other faster way?

Comment: Post the **exact** table definitions, including all indexes. Also post the 3 queries generated.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I add the table defination & queries(it 5 now not 3)

Comment: The LINQ query definitely can be improved. But note that different query providers (ORMs) process LINQ queries differently. What is the target ORM - LinqToSQL, EF6, EF Core?

Comment: @IvanStoev EF6 and I test that linq in linqPad5

Comment: I'm not familiar with LinqPad, but for sure the real EF6 will not produce such SQL queries. In fact it will produce and execute a single (eventually big) SQL query. I would suggest you testing in real environment (or configure LinqPad for the intended target ORM).